# Opencart: Query the database to get tax_rate data

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to get a calculator helper in product admin page, near the price input I want to add a textbox that helps users to calculate the price with Tax VAT exluded to insert.
It's something similar to this [PLUGIN](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7045) but I need to query the database to get an array of all Tax Rates and compare them with the `tax_class_id` selected by user just below the price.

I have found a sort of request in this page: `admin/controller/localisation/tax_rate.php`

```php
if (isset($this->request->post['rate'])) {
    $this->data['rate'] = $this->request->post['rate'];
} elseif (!empty($tax_rate_info)) {
    $this->data['rate'] = $tax_rate_info['rate'];
} else {
    $this->data['rate'] = '';
}
```

But I have no idea how to query the database and get the data inside the page `admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl`.
I'm trying to get a result similar to Prestashop's price management.

Please give me some help!

EDIT:

I solved with this code added in `admin/controller/catalog/product.php` placed inside getForm() function:

```
$sql = 'SELECT tra.rate, tra.type, tru.tax_class_id FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'tax_rate tra LEFT JOIN '.DB_PREFIX.'tax_rule tru ON tru.tax_rate_id = tra.tax_rate_id WHERE tru.tax_class_id IS NOT NULL' ;
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$rates = array();
foreach($query->rows as $result){
    $rates[] = $result;
}
$this->data['rates'] = $rates;
```

thanks to all the participants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get list of rates, use this code:

```php
// get tax rates
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'tax_rate ';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$rates = array();
foreach($query->rows as $result){
    $rates[] = $result;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [tax_rate_id] => 86
        [geo_zone_id] => 3
        [name] => VAT (17.5%)
        [rate] => 17.5000
        [type] => P
        [date_added] => 2011-03-09 21:17:10
        [date_modified] => 2011-09-22 22:24:29
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tax_rate_id] => 87
        [geo_zone_id] => 3
        [name] => Eco Tax (-2.00)
        [rate] => 2.0000
        [type] => F
        [date_added] => 2011-09-21 21:49:23
        [date_modified] => 2011-09-23 00:40:19
    )

)
```

EDIT:
The code above goes in the controller. To pass data to template use something like:

```
$this->data['rates'] = $rates;
```

Then this data will be accessible in view through `$rates`.
Sorry for not clarifying this from the start. In other words, `$this->data` holds all variables for the view: `$this->data['foo']` becomes `$foo` in the template file (view).

Comment: this is quite clear, but i'm just learning about the opencart MVC structure and i miss the way to get this $rates[] avaible in the .tpl file.
I must use your code in controller/catalog/product.php? in model? or directly in the view?

Answer (score 1):

I have also developed a `price including VAT` extension for OpenCart so I am able to give You some advice on how to move on:

1. using jQuery handle the

   - *Tax Class* selectbox's `change` event
   - *Price* / *Price Helper* input `keyup` event (or any that You wish to)
   - by querying the database (within controller's action invoked by AJAX request) with the code like
     `SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'tax_rate tra LEFT JOIN '.DB_PREFIX.'tax_rule tru ON tru.tax_rate_id = tra.tax_rate_id WHERE tru.tax_class_id = ' . (int)$this->request->get['tax_class_id']`
     where the `tax_class_id` index is retrieved from the GET from the AJAX call
2. now that You have the `tax_rate` You can calculate the prices (I am doing this both-ways, even a person inputs price excluding VAT the price including VAT getd calculated and vice versa...)

I am sorry I cannot give You the concrete code but if I did that I could go directly to OpenCart extensions and delete my price including VAT extension ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I think it's not needed an ajax call, i was thinking to query all data from tax_rate and tax_class tables, then work with results locally.