# Opencart how to get exchange rate

Tags: php, opencart

In opencart 1.5.6 I have an attribute expressed in price (such as the price of insurance for a car). 
Prices are quoted in one currency (say USD) and are recalculated according to exchange rate which opencart auto updates daily. 
With changing of a currency I am recalculating the attribute value. For now I am updating the exchange rate value manually.

Is there a way to get the exchange rate which Opencart daily updates and stores  ?
- INPUT     $_SESSION['currency']
- OUTPUT    exchange rate       (to default currency (in which the attribute is quoted))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the value that is stored in the back-end, then yes there is a possibility, you would just have to add a function in the corresponding model and call it in the controller afterwards, this function will return you the rate.

This would take some time and some programming skills to start with.

Hope i helped!

Comment: Oh yes .. it is stored in a database but I didnt know where is it stored and how to call it. However it was pretty simple, I just modified [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599779/opencart-query-the-database-to-get-tax-rate-data)
-instead of tax i used currency